# How a Spark executor runs multiple tasks?

Tags: scala, hadoop, apache-spark, hadoop-yarn

For example, if number of executors are 40, but number of tasks are 80, that means each executor would be running two tasks in parallel. Also my functions (which tasks execute) are not normal functions, but I call programs inside them. So, each task actually takes several minutes to complete. So, my question is, how does Spark manages that? Would those tasks share the executor's JVM? What about number of cores, would it be divided among those two tasks? What if don't want those two tasks to run simultaneously, but execute them in round-robin fashion, that is, run the first task with all of the executor's cores, and only when its finished, run the second task?

Answer (score 3):

it depends how you allocate your resources i.e. number of cores, cores per executors and allocated memory to the executors. it also depends on how you program to attain maximum parallelism.

it also depends how you code to attain the maximum parallelism. if there are two tasks and they are independent of each other they will run in parallel. if one task depend on the result of previous task they will execute serially.

yes number of cores can be divided into two tasks by making two executors and allocating the available cores to it.

for executing the tasks in round robin fashion you need to define the partitioning scheme and allocate the resources according to it. this will ensure that each task is executed after other task.

Comment: Can you please elaborate a bit about the partitioning scheme to execute tasks in round robin fashion?

Comment: i can tell about a use case that i have come across. so i was using a data frame to store the data. initially i had a single partition so the complete partition was executed in a single executor leaving the other executors unused. then i tried to partition the data frame using re-partition function() now these partitions were running in parallel across executors. so when i had two executors each executor processed around the 100 partitions serially reducing the time to half. each partition is  considered as a single task when executing. so for i executor every task will run serially.

Comment: Actually it depends on how many executor cores you specify. Spark will run as many parallel tasks as the number of cores you have specified. So, if you have 4 executors and 4 executor cores, in total 4 x 4 = 16 tasks would be running in parallel. So one way I've found to solve my problem is to limit the number of executor cores. In that case, things would be done in a more round robin fashion.